# Is there a way to access ps.map in python?

Tags: python, arcpy, grass-gis, export, printing

I am wondering whether its possible using python interface to load layers and edit them in Print/Cartographic Composer without displaying, and finally export to PDF?

Something that can be done via ArcPy (ArcGIS python module).

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways:

- Make use of the code for the [WxGUI Cartographic Composer](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Cartographic_Composer)
- Interface directly to ps.map with the [GRASS-Python API](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python)

Note that an improved Python API is under development in the current [Google Summer of Code](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_SoC_Ideas_2012#Accepted_Ideas)

Comment: thanks for your response. could you tell a bit more on how to 'Interface directly to ps.map with the GRASS-Python API'?

Comment: Well, you need to create the ASCII control file for ps.map, then call the ps.map module